# what are prototype cells in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, tableview, prototype, cells

I was wondering what are prototype cells in xcode?
And how does the following code work when it creates 4 different types of labels by using switch and prototype cells? I was wondering about the switch case in particular

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    as! DetailTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = "Name"
cell.valueLabel.text = restaurant.name
case 1:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = "Type"
cell.valueLabel.text = restaurant.type
case 2:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = "Location"
cell.valueLabel.text = restaurant.location
case 3:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = "Been here"
cell.valueLabel.text = (restaurant.isVisited) ? "Yes, I’ve been here before" : "No"
default:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
cell.valueLabel.text = ""
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a model for table view cell. You create the model, and then using this switch statement it will change the "fieldLabel" text to the correct value. Then place the cell in the table, and render it to the user/

Research switch statements, and iOS table view cells.

[Objective-C Switch Statement](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/learn-objectivec-the-switch-statement/53)

[iOS Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html)